# Oauth 2.0 exchange authorization code for token : Invalid scheme for redirect uri

Tags: google-app-engine, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, google-oauth-java-client

i'm trying to exchange a received authorization code wth a token in a web application but when I call GoogleAuthorizationCodeTokenRequest i get this error : 
"Invalid parameter value for redirect_uri: 
Invalid scheme:https://mapmydayunamur.appspot.com/getauthcodeservlet"

I've tried many redirect_uri and don't know why I get this error.
The Uri is in my redirect Uri in developers console.
Here's my code : 
in getauthcodeservlet.java :

```
String authcode = req.getParameter("code");
        String clientID = "CLIENTID_FROM_GOOGLEDEVELOPERSCONSOLE"
        String clientSecret = "CLIENTSECRET_FROM_GOOGLEDEVELOPERSCONSOLE";
        String redirectUri = "https://mapmydayunamur.appspot.com/getauthcodeservlet";

try {
                GoogleTokenResponse response =
                    new GoogleAuthorizationCodeTokenRequest(new NetHttpTransport(), new JacksonFactory(),clientID, clientSecret, authcode,redirectUri).execute();
                resp.getWriter().println("Access token: " + response.getAccessToken());
              } catch (TokenResponseException e) {
                if (e.getDetails() != null) {
                    resp.getWriter().println("Error: " + e.getDetails().getError());
                  if (e.getDetails().getErrorDescription() != null) {
                      resp.getWriter().println(e.getDetails().getErrorDescription());
                  }
                  if (e.getDetails().getErrorUri() != null) {
                      resp.getWriter().println(e.getDetails().getErrorUri());
                  }
                } else {
                    resp.getWriter().println(e.getMessage());
                }
              }
    }
```

Thanks for helping me

Comment: space character in front of the https?  " https...

Comment: Sorry it was an error when copy-paste my code into the forum.
Now it's the good version, doesn't work neither..

Thanks for your answer anyway !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved by inruducing the redirect_uri via

```
.setRedirectUri(getRedirectUri(req))
```

and adding the method

```
  static String getRedirectUri(HttpServletRequest req) {
        GenericUrl requestUrl = new GenericUrl(req.getRequestURL().toString());
        requestUrl.setRawPath("/getauthcodeservlet");
        return requestUrl.build();
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot specify a subdirectory. Per Google's documentation when changing Client Credential settings in the developer's console:

> Cannot contain a wildcard (http://*.example.com) or a path
>   (http://example.com/subdir).

So you should change to `https://mapmydayunamur.appspot.com`